# webclient less than 3 seconds response or 45 seconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I have a very basic spring boot 2.2.4 application that queries a downstream system using webclient with a blocking call. I am not doing any configuration of the webclient (setting timeouts, etc.), just using it "out of the box".

What I find is that the response time of the webclient call is either below 3 seconds or **precisely 45 seconds**, which I find very strange. Why if the response is slow, it is **always** 45 seconds?

The only reference to the 45 seconds I could find comes from the Reactor Netty documentation:

> 4.6. Connection Pool
>
> By default, the TCP client uses a “fixed” connection pool with 500 as the maximum number of the channels and 45s as the acquisition timeout. This means that the implementation creates a new channel if someone tries to acquire a channel but none is in the pool. When the maximum number of the channels in the pool is reached, new tries to acquire a channel are delayed until a channel is returned to the pool again. The implementation uses FIFO order for channels in the pool. By default, there is no idle time specified for the channels in the pool.

Does anybody have any suggestion as to why my slow webclient calls always take 45 seconds to complete?

Comment: When a call takes 45s, does it succeed or fail?  If it fails, that is the error?

Comment: Also, try connecting with an IP address instead of domain name.  That will eliminate or indicate possible problems related to DNS

Comment: @Matt, it succeeds, never a failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the fixed pool size which is 500. If all these connections (channels) are currently in use by existing requests, a new request for a connection would be queued until one of the 500 connections becomes free. If WebClient isn't able to acquire a connection within 45 seconds for a new request (since all of the 500 channels are still blocked by existing requests), it fails with an AcquireTimeout Exception. I'm assuming the ones that finished before 3 seconds are success ones while the 45 second ones are failures. Depending on the Throughput of your application, you can adjust the pool size accordingly.

Comment: The 45 seconds ones succeed as well - no failures.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when I've seen delays like this on successful connections, it was caused like this:

1. You try to connect with a domain name, so the client calls DNS first to get an address;
2. DNS returns address records for both IPv4 and IPv6
3. The client tries IPv6 first, but IPv6 is not properly configured on the network, and this fails *after the IPv6 connection timeout*, which can be in the 45s range.
4. The client then tries IPv4, which succeeds.

Whether or not this happens to you depends on your OS+version, your java version, and the configuration of your network.

Try connecting with in IPv4 IP address, like http://192.168.10.1/the/rest.  If it's always fast then you probably had a problem like above.  Unfortunately you can't usually connect this way with HTTPS, but depending on your OS you could try stuffing the correct v4 address in /etc/hosts.

Look here for more: https://serverfault.com/questions/548777/how-to-prevent-delays-associated-with-ipv6-aaaa-records

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to this netty issue:

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1012

I will have a look at that first now.

Thanks for all the replies!